# chroot can't execute /etc/apparmor/inittramfs

Tags: boot, chroot, svn

We've old Ubuntu on our server, which is used for SVN commits. It is our SVN server. We don't want to lose the data which is for last 10 years committed there. We don't want to lose the svn commit history. But this days when booting the system it is showing following error. I don't know the Ubuntu/SVN version

```
chroot cannot execute /etc/apparmor/initramfs no such file or directory
run-init /sbin/init no such file or directory
kernel panic not syncing Attempted to kill init!
```

Please help me to up the server without losing SVN repos with history.

Comment: If you have no `/sbin/init`, then something is very wrong with that system :( I would make a sector level backup of the disk data ASAP.

Comment: I am layman for linux, any suggestion how to make sector level back up. Will that have svn commit history too.

Comment: Plug in a USB hard disk larger than the HDD in the system, and boot a Ubuntu LiveCD, and run something similar to the `dd` command given in the question: http://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning Be sure to get the devices right! This will save all data that still exists on your HDD. At this stage, there is no telling what may or may not be salvageable from that.

Comment: Here is what I did. I've downloaded latest Ubuntu 16.01 and made usb bootable. I have chosen rescue system. Now i'm in shell in installer environment. Don't know what to do. Any suggestion, can I install this new Ubuntu without losing anything. Anything please suggest.